# Inserting multiple lines containing backslashes/special characters after a certain line in a file via sed

Tags: bash, scripting, sed

I am writing a script to try and speed up my basic Wordpress installation. It downloads the latest version, unpacks it, changes to the clients name and then updates some text in the config file.

I am however having trouble inserting multiple lines which contains special characters using sed. The multiple lines are from the WP Secret Key Generator https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ and they are to replace the standard

```
define('AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here');
```

etc...

Here is the bit of code that is giving me the issue

```
# Download data to variable
salt="`curl https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/`"

sed -i "/NONCE_SALT/a $salt" $pname/wp-config-sample.php
```

I am downloading the generated text to a variable and then looking to insert, on a new line, after the last instance in the standard text (I will later delete all of these standard lines). It throws up an error of;

```
"ed: -e expression #1, char 112: extra characters after command"
```

When I enter a single line of standard text it is fine. If I add quotation marks around the `$salt` it just prints the literal `$salt` in the file.

Is sed the right approach for inserting this data? Keeping in mind I need to insert after a specific point in the file?

Any hints or tips are more than welcome. This is my first attempt at a bash script.

Comment: No, sed is the wrong tool. sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for any other text manipulation else you should use awk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `a` function requires that a backslash precede any internal newline in the string. So, one approach is to use `sed` to add the necessary backslashes:

```
# Download data to variable, adding \ to all but the last line:
salt="$(curl https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ | sed '$ ! s/$/\\/')"

sed -i "/NONCE_SALT/a $salt" "$pname/wp-config-sample.php"
```

(Note that I used `$(...)` instead of `` `...` ``: the latter has painful quoting rules. In this case I'd have had to write `\\\\` instead of `\\`.)

That said, in this case I think it might be simpler to save the salt-stuff to a temporary-file, and use `r` instead of `a`:

```
# Download data to the file salt.txt:
curl https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ > salt.txt

sed -i "/NONCE_SALT/r salt.txt" "$pname/wp-config-sample.php"

rm salt.txt      # could also be done in a trap
```

Comment: Hi, Both of these work fine, apart from that the final step of the insert is adding ^M to the end of every line except the newly inserted ones. Any ideas how to insert without adding these or should I do another sed to remove these?

Comment: @edwardgd: Sorry, I'm confused. Are you saying that you want every `wp-config-sample.php` to use Windows line-endings (`\r\n`, ^M^J), *except* for the part that came from `https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/`, which should use Unix line-endings (`\n`, ^J)?

Comment: No it's not that I want it to. It is just that when I run your bit of code it adds ^M to every line EXCEPT the newly added ones from $salt. I can clean it up using the dos2unix command, but I wonder if it is necessary? cheers

Comment: @edwardgd: Re: "It is just that when I run your bit of code it adds ^M to every line EXCEPT the newly added ones from $salt": Are you sure? I'm betting that what actually happens is, `wp-config-sample.php` *already* has ^M at the end of every line, and this `sed` command merely *doesn't* add ^M in the part that it inserts. If you want consistency, you can either run `dos2unix "$pname/wp-config-sample.php"` before this step, or else run `unix2dos salt.txt` between the `curl` and `sed` commands.

Comment: Cool thanks. yeah I've inserted teh unix2dos command in there. Was just checking as I am still very much learning. Cheers for all your help :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
awk -v salt="$(curl https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/)" '
    {print} /NONCE_SALT/{print salt}
' "$pname/wp-config-sample.php" > tmp$$ && mv tmp$$ "$pname/wp-config-sample.php"
```

Unlike sed, awk is unaffected by backslahes or quotes or newlines any other characters than can cause sed to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of forming the file `wp-config.php` by substituting the contents of `$salt` into file `wp-config-sample.php` and otherwise editing wp-config-sample.php in place, it is more straightforward to use `egrep -v` to remove lines from `wp-config-sample.php`, and then concatenate the necessary new lines at the end.  That is, create a script to do the following three steps, with appropriate code substituted for `write-customer-stuff`:

```
egrep -v 'name_here|word_here|unique phrase here' wp-config-sample.php > wp-config.php
write-customer-stuff >> wp-config.php  
curl https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ >> wp-config.php
```

You might also add a line like the following for rudimentary error checking:

```
[ $(wc -l < wp-config.php) -eq $(wc -l < wp-config-sample.php) ] || echo '*** Lengths of wp-config.php and wp-config-sample.php are different ***'
```